# CSS3 Transitions: is there an on click option without using JQuery?

Tags: css, click, hover, transition

This works great:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
    div
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    transition:width 2s;
    -moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
    }

    div:hover
    {
    width:300px;
    }
    </style>
```

But does anyone know of a way to do this using click instead of hover? And not involving JQuery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can write like this:

**CSS**

```
input{display:none}
.ani
    {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    transition:width 2s;
    -moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
    display:block;
    }
input:checked + .ani{width:300px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="button">
<label class="ani" for="button"></label>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/nMNJE/

Comment: Thanks! THis is pretty close to what I want!

Answer (score 3):

You have two options, one using javascript and one using the CSS pseudo-class "active".  The javascript method will be supported on older browsers, and is what i would recommend.  However, to use the CSS method just change div:hover to div:active.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function expand(){
    document.getElementById('id').style.width="300px";
}
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
div#id
{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:red;
transition:width 2s;
-moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="id" onClick="expand()">
    Div Content...
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a click selector without using javasccript. You can affect differente DOM elements using **:target** pseudo class. 
If an element is the destination of an anchor target it will get the **:target** pseudo element (to influence the clicked element just set the ID the same as its anchor tag).

```
<style>
a { color:black; }
a:target { color:red; }
</style>

<a id="elem" href="#elem">Click me</a>
```

Here is a fiddle to play with :  https://jsfiddle.net/k86b81jv/

Answer (score 0):

there is no css selector for clicks without using sass, so using jquery is probably your best bet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#DIV_ID').click(function(){
$(this).animate({width:'300px'},200);
});
});
```

((don't forget to include the plugin link in your header!!))

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```