# CSS3 transition click event

Tags: css

I wand to implement a click event in css3 transition for a div tag. I want it to be like a normal button click event. Still I couldn't find a way to do this. Please can any one help me on this.

Comment: He asked for CSS, no jquery ...

Comment: do you have already a bit of html and css  ? jsfiddle or something similar

Comment: You can't do DOM operations using CSS.. use javascript or jquery for click event. and in that click event add the class which holds the css transitions.

Comment: Is it ok to use javascript to handle the click event? Although there are some clever CSS tricks to work with a click event, they are very hacky and browser specific.

Comment: @Hendrik **Yes** it is perfectly ok to use JS for click event.

Answer (score 6):

As per **CSS3** transitions:

```
div
{
    transition-property: width;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

`transition-property`: *Specifies the name of the CSS property to which the transition is applied.*

`transition-duration`: *Defines the length of time that a transition takes. Default 0.*

`transition-timing-function`: *Describes how the speed during a transition will be calculated. Default "ease".*

`transition-delay`: *Defines when the transition will start. Default 0.*

One more property to use all the rest:
`transition`: *A shorthand property for setting the four transition properties into a single property.*

```
div
{
    transition: width 1s linear 2s;
}
```

**Or** if you want to use plain css pseudo-classes:

Given this html:

```
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Use these pseudo-classes:

```
button { }
button:hover { background-color: lime; }
button:active { background-color: fuchsia; }
button:focus { background-color: yellow; }
```

`:hover` is when the mouse is over the element.

`:active` is when the element is clicked (and hold).

`:focus` is when you tab to the element.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

You have two basic options:

- **Use the pseudo-class `:active` in your CSS**.  The element will then transition to the `:active` state when clicked (assuming an anchor).  Although this isn't necessarily the best bet if you need wide browser-coverage (ie: not supported by older browsers), it is the only option for a pure-CSS implementation.
- **Use JavaScript**.  Using JavaScript, you can switch the element's class on-click, which will allow you to change the appearance of the element (including any transitions you have set on it).  Something like:

  ```
  $('.selector').click(function(e){
      $(this).toggleClass('new-class');
      e.preventDefault();
  });
  ```

There is a third - very hacky - option which involves using a sibling form input (a checkbox) and inheriting off it's `checked` state, but it's probably not what you're looking for.

For posterity's sake, here's a Fiddle that demonstrates what I'm talking about (from [a previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166580/css3-transitions-is-there-an-on-click-option-without-using-jquery)): http://jsfiddle.net/nMNJE/