# Div Page Transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I try make a transition fade page with div content, this is my horizontal header menu

```
<ul id="navigation" class="select">
    <div id="teste">
            <li><a id="link-home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="about" href="#about">about</a></li>
    <li><a id="contact" href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </div>
```

and this is the example of content

```
<div id="home">
      <h2>this is home</h2>
</div>
<div id="about">
      <h2>this is about</h2>
</div>
<div id="contact">
      <h2>this is contact</h2>
</div>
```

I need that #home is showing the homepage, and other hidden, when you click on the link to use the fade effect to the next page (which is the case in div) . 
what is the best way? css3 or jquery? or both? Can someone help me make this script?

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. We also need to see your existing CSS. If you go to jsfiddle.net, recreate your layout and add the link to your post, you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the navigation to fade in the new content rather than linking to a different page.  In that case, either CSS3 or jQuery could work, but I would recommend jQuery because it is browser backwards compatible.  Anything older that IE 9 will not interpret the CSS3 transitions.  Plus, there is not a good way to detect clicks in CSS3 (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166580/css3-transitions-is-there-an-on-click-option-without-using-jquery)), so you'd end up using jQuery there anyway.  Here is the code:

Menu:

```
<ul id="navigation" class="select">
    <div id="test">
        <li><a id="link-home" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a id="link-about" href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a id="link-contact" href="#">contact</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Content:

```
<div id="home">
      <h2>This is home.</h2>
</div>
<div id="about">
      <h2>This is about.</h2>
</div>
<div id="contact">
      <h2>This is contact.</h2>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var animTime = 600;
    $("#about").hide();
    $("#contact").hide();
    $('#link-home').click(function() {
        $("#about").fadeOut(animTime);
        $("#contact").fadeOut(animTime);
        $("#home").delay(animTime).fadeIn(animTime);
    });
    $('#link-about').click(function() {
        $("#home").fadeOut(animTime);
        $("#contact").fadeOut(animTime);
        $("#about").delay(animTime).fadeIn(animTime);
    });
    $('#link-contact').click(function() {
        $("#home").fadeOut(animTime);
        $("#about").fadeOut(animTime);
        $("#contact").delay(animTime).fadeIn(animTime);
    });
});
```

This should work with any code you already have.  Just make sure your ids in the markup match the ids in the jQuery and you will be good to go.  If you want to adjust the fade in time, just change the value of `animTime`.  This number measures the animation time in milliseconds.  The actual time the animation takes will be double the `animTime` because the other div's are animated out and then the new one is animated in.